# How to rotate a CGVector by a right angle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I want to store direction of my sprite as `CGVector`,

I have only 4 possible vectors:

```
CGVector up     = CGVectorMake(0,    100);
CGVector down   = CGVectorMake(0,   -100);
CGVector left   = CGVectorMake(-100,    0);
CGVector right  = CGVectorMake(100,   0);
```

and I have 2 events:

```
-(void) turnLeft;
-(void) turnRight;
```

in case that now `(my_sprite.direction == CGVector(0,100))` and event turnRight happened how can I get `CGVector(100, 0)`???

P.S. I don't want to many if or switch statements, because in the future should be much more vectors.

Comment: my_sprite.direction = right, from that example and explanation it looks like you need to assign the vector, not add it

Comment: If you only have 2 events which are left and right, why do you need up and down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want the ability to use more directions in the future, It would be better to just store angle and speed.

```
- (void)applyDirectionChange{
    CGFloat x = sinf(self.angle)*self.speed;
    CGFloat y = cosf(self.angle)*self.speed;
    self.direction = CGVectorMake(x,y);
}  

- (void)turnRight{
    self.angle += 90*M_PI/180;
    [self applyDirectionChange];
}

- (void)turnLeft{
    self.angle -= 90*M_PI/180;
    [self applyDirectionChange];
}
```

if you still want to keep your constant vectors, put them in an array in the right order and have an current direction index pointing to the right vector:

```
//declarations
NSUInteger currentDirectionIndex;
NSUInteger numDirections;
CGVector[4] directions;

//initialize them somewhere
currentDirectionIndex = 0;
numDirections = 4; 
directions[0] = up;
directions[1] = right;
directions[2] = down;
directions[3] = left;

//in your methods
- (void)turnRight{
    currentDirectionIndex++;
    if(currentDirectionIndex>=numDirections)
        currentDirectionIndex = 0;

    self.direction = directions[currentDirectionIndex];
}

- (void)turnLeft{
    currentDirectionIndex--;
    if(currentDirectionIndex<0)
        currentDirectionIndex = numDirections-1;

    self.direction = directions[currentDirectionIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's rearrange your vectors into this order:

```
CGVector up     = CGVectorMake(   0,    100);
CGVector right  = CGVectorMake( 100,      0);
CGVector down   = CGVectorMake(   0,   -100);
CGVector left   = CGVectorMake(-100,      0);
```

Now we can see that rotating a vector 90 degrees clockwise is the same as swapping the coordinates and then negating the Y coordinate:

```
CGVector vectorByRotatingVectorClockwise(CGVector in) {
    CGVector out;
    out.dx = in.dy;
    out.dy = -in.dx;
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, but he says that "in the future" there "should be much more vectors". Then that will not work anymore (at least not this simplified rotation case)

Comment: Swap and negate Y rotates *every* 2D vector by 90 degrees.  If he wants to rotate by a smaller amount, he can clarify that and I will update my answer.

Comment: hey Rob, this is true engineer approach)